# Mule-Unable to access Session Variable value in another flow

Tags: mule, mule-component

I need to retrieve the value set in session variable in flow1 to flow2. The code I've written looks like this :

```
<flow name="demo1Flow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="demo" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <set-session-variable variableName="name" value="balwant" doc:name="Session Variable"/>
    <logger message="Inside demo1 #[sessionVars.name]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="/test" method="GET" doc:name="HTTP"/>
</flow>
<flow name="demoFlow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/test" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <logger message="Inside demo flow #[sessionVars['name']]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>
```

With the above code I'm not able to get the value from session variable which was set in demo1Flow to demoFlow. The output for this flow I'm getting is :

```
INFO  2017-03-07 12:55:28,455 [[demo].HTTP_Listener_Configuration.worker.01]     org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Inside demo1 balwant
INFO  2017-03-07 12:55:28,536 [[demo].HTTP_Listener_Configuration.worker.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Inside demo flow null.
```

As the documentation says that value in Session variable is accessible across the session in different flows, but here that is not happening :(. Not sure what is the reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Referring [Session Variable Transformer Reference](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/session-variable-transformer-reference) documentation, the Session Variable persist for the entire message lifecycle, regardless of transport barriers, except for the HTTP Connector which doesn’t propagate them.

Answer (score 2):

They are two independent flows which process messages based on different input paths, although you are calling using http requester from flow1,second has its own scope.
For every flow it's scope begins with its inbound.

As there is no relationship between those two flows, you can't access anything from flow1 in the other. If you want that variable you can set as outbound property then it will become inbound property to the second flow. Otherwise you can set as uri parameters.

Regards,
Mallesh